# Searborn palette = [palette[h] for h in hue_names] KeyError: 3.0 - all values have been specified in the palette

Tags: seaborn

with .unique()) i printed out all values in the column 'hue' which i have assigned in my color palette, yet i get the error: [palette[h] for h in hue_names] KeyError: 3.0

> 

```
print(MPT_CPT['Bodenklasse'].unique()) -> Result [nan  4.  5.  6.  7.  9.  8.  3.]
SBTcolour = {'3':'#FF98CB', '4' : '#7F7F7F', '5' : '#CACACA', '6': '#C7D239', '7': '#B3E090', '8': '#FFC484', '9': '#FFDFB9'} #'10' : '#FFFFD2', '1': '#FF0000', '2': '#DBAC63',
sns.lmplot(data=MPT_CPT, x="Sn [ppm]" , y="qc", ci=None, hue="Bodenklasse", palette=SBTcolour)
```

I even left out the colours that are not in the column. I had values with 0 in 'Bodenklasse' which I had to convert to nan because i dont need them. Ideas ?

Comment: Your code is hard to understand. Is it possible that your keys have to be strings and you pass a float?

Comment: Did you try `3.0:'#FF98CB'` instead of `'3':'#FF98CB'`?  Further, you could add `hue_order=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` to explicitly filter out the zeros. Or `data=MPT_CPT[ MPT_CPT['Bodenklasse'] != 0 ]`.